# Curious why print statement is executed with every line, when the goal is only to have it print once, at the bottom of the list

Tags: python, for-loop

Code below:

```py
requested_trades = ['long only', 'short only', 'neutral position']
for requested_trade in requested_trades:
  print(f"My Trade List: {requested_trade}.")

  print("\nExecute them well")
```

The output:

> ```
> My Trade List: long only.
>
> Execute them well
> My Trade List: short only.
>
> Execute them well
> My Trade List: neutral position.
>
> Execute them well
> ```

I was under the belief "Execute them well" should only appear at the bottom line.

Comment: You need to unindent the *`print("\nExecute them well")`* line. Because of the way it's indented, it is included in the loop, so it repeats for every `requested_trade`

Comment: Was there a particular reason why you believed that?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't use curly braces or keywords such as `do/end` to define blocks. It uses white-space indentation. Anything indented at the same level is part of that block, even if you put in a blank newline.

The following will do what you expect:

```
requested_trades = ['long only', 'short only', 'neutral position']
for requested_trade in requested_trades:
  print(f"My Trade List: {requested_trade}.")

print("\nExecute them well")
```